# Nueva entidad encontrada a través de la relación

Tags: php, symfony3, orm, symfony, doctrine

1. Tengo un proyecto en Symfony.
2. Creo un formulario para una entidad nueva.

   ```
   class EquipoType extends AbstractType{
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $equipo = new Equipo();

       $builder
       ->add('unidades', IntegerType::class)
       ->add('accionComercial', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\adelantoequipos\AccionComercial',
           'em' => 'adeq',
           'choices' => $equipo->getAccionComercial(),
           'choice_label' => 'nombre',
           'placeholder' => 'Elija Accion Comercial'
       ))
       ->add('modelo', TextType::class)
       ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
               'label' => 'Guardar Equipo',
               'attr' => array(
                   'class' => "btn btn-info",
                   'style' => "margin-top: 7px; margin-left:40%;"
               ))
       );

       $builder->get('modelo')
           ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
               function ($modelo) {
                   return $modelo ? $modelo->getModDescModelo() :  $modelo;
               },
               function ($modelo) use ($options) {
                   return $modelo ? $options['em']->getRepository(ModModelo::class)->findOneBy(array(
                       'modDescModelo' => $modelo
                   )) : $modelo;
               }
           ));
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\adelantoequipos\Equipo',
           'em' => "adeq"
       ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
       return 'appbundle_indicogpt_adelantoequipos_equipo';
    }
   }
   ```
3. Esta entidad tiene una relación. (Un Equipo tiene un modelo, un modelo puede ser de muchos Equipos)

   ```
   class Equipo
   {
       /**
    * @var \AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modelo_id", referencedColumnName="MOD_ID_MODELO")
    * })
    */
   private $modelo;
   ```
4. Los modelos ya están en la BD, es decir. Que un equipo solo debe guardar la id ya existente de un Modelo. Controller:

   ```
   public function crearEquipo(Request $request){

   $emAdeq = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('adeq');
   $emCatalogo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('catalogo');

   $equipo = new Equipo();
   $form = $this->createForm(EquipoType::class, $equipo, array(
       'action' => "crearEquipo",
       'em' =>  $emCatalogo,
       'attr' => array(
           'class' => "form"
       )
   ));

   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

       $equipo = $form->getData();

       $emAdeq->persist($equipo);

       $emAdeq->flush();

       $this->addFlash('exito', $equipo->getId());

       return $this->redirectToRoute('portadaAdelantoEquipos');
   }


   return $this->render('AppBundle:AdelantoEquipos/forms:adelantosForm.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView()
   ));
   ```

   }
5. Cuando voy a Grabar el nuevo Equipo me dice que ha encontrado una
   nueva entidad en la relación, pero esa entidad no es nueva, si no
   que es un modelo ya existente que ahora esta relacionado con el
   Equipo.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   Como se aprecia en la imagen, elijo un modelo de los existentes mediante un campo de autocompletado.

Justo antes de hacer el **Persist** de la entidad, puedo ver en el debugger el objeto que voy a grabar y aparece bien compuesto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es el siguiente:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\adelantoequipos\Equipo#modelo' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo@0000000011088ca600000000661c7dca. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo#__toString()' to get a clue.

No entiedno porqué tiene un código numérico @0000000012ce55020000000059452bb5 ni porque piensa que es una nueva entidad.

**Alguien sabe que comportamiento está teniendo Doctrine?**

**¿Como puedo grabar la entidad Equipo con su relación?**

He visto problemas parecidos que los solucionan seteando de nuevo los objetos extrayéndolos de la base de datos, pero eso conlleva setear demasiadas relaciones. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771285/symfony2-doctrine-a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relationship)

Comment: Sin ver el codigo de entidades, servicio y/o formBuilder es difícil determinarlo. Todo apunta a que se está creando una nueva instancia de `modelo` asociado al equipo.

Comment: Así es, y no debería de crear una nueva instacia. A lo largo del dia subiré el procedimiento. Gracias

Comment: Sí, es realmente ver el Form y la acción con la que guardas para brindar una buena ayuda!

Comment: He editado el Post, añadiendo toda la información que tengo @JorgeEduardoAdan

Comment: También sería útil que ingresaras a la opción "Doctrine" en el profiler de symfony, para que revises el mapping de la base de datos, nada debe salir en rojo, también se puede hacer si corres el comando > php app/console doctrine:schema:validate

Comment: Las entidades están mapeadas en diferentes Entity Manager?

Comment: @JorgeEduardoAdan Ningún error me sale con el comando que indicas ni revisando el profiler de doctrine...Me tiro de los pelos!!! hoy lo tengo que solucinar

Comment: @JorgeEduardoAdan Si que están mappeadas en diferentes entities manager ya que cada una es de una bd diferente.
Sin embargo, tengo otro caso que relaciona las misma bases de datos y no tengo ese problem!!

Comment: por cierto en la version 3 el comando es `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Comment: No habías indicado que era symfony 3, en fin, podrías intentar poner en el formulario, dentro del EntityType la opción >"mapped" =>false,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estaba usando **dos** entityManager ya que la relacion está hecha en dos bases de datos diferentes.

Pero no he caido en la cuenta de que la entidad relacionada tiene establecida su base de datos por lo que solo necesito un EntityManager. Ya que con uno me devuelve las relaciones

Al tener dos entityManagers me pedia que grabase dos veces.

Solucion: Establece en la entidad su BD: `*@ORM\Table(name="adelantoequipos.adelanto"`
Donde he urilizado `$emCatalgo` reemplazarlo por `$emAdeq` y eliminar el de catálogo ya que queda inservible.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo ese cartel te dice detalladamente el problema que tienes. Lo que sucede es que pueden ocurrir errores de implementación a la hora de acceder al Modelo en la entidad Equipo y tambien te dice que pruebes hacer esto para resolverlo:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IndicoGpt\catalogo\ModModelo", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumns({
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modelo_id", referencedColumnName="MOD_ID_MODELO")
```

agrega cascade={"persist"} donde declaras la la relación.

Comment: El problema es que si agrego el persist lo que hace es crear el modelo asociado al equipo en la base de datos modelo, siendo que ese modelo ya existe. Es decir, si añado el persist, me da un error de duplicidad, no puede insertar un modelo con la clave x ya que ya existe ese registro.
El mensaje de error me da que pensar que no estoy haceindo algo bien pasos atrás.